Why electrophile doesn't attack COO- in 4-pentenoic acid?
When 4−pentenoic acid is treated with $\ce{I2}$ and $\ce{NaHCO3}$, it gives 5−iodomethyl−dihydrofuran−2−one:

But why does the electrophile (in this case $\ce{I+}$) is attacking the pi bond and not attacking the oxygen which is electron rich and probably also have negative charge due to formation of $\ce{H2CO3}$.
So, what is the reaction mechanism involved in this?

It is entirely possible that the $\ce{I^+}$ end of a polarized iodine molecule does attack the carboxylate oxygen. But if it does, the resulting bond is weak and potentially quite reversible via the displaced iodide ion re-attacking the site. The alternative mechanism of the electrophilic iodine attacking the double bond followed by the carboxylate ion doing so as a nucleophile is more irreversible, and so that product is the one seen to accumulate.

There is not going to be a free $\ce{I+}$, but a ploarised $\ce{I2}$. I don't think $\ce{R-CO2-}$ is going to split that bond (in such mild conditions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodolactonization

@Martin Usually I use "moiety" to describe a part of a molecule that acts as a certain species would (e.g. carbanion moiety in a Grignard reagent). Is there a better term?

Apologies, I'm not disagreeing with your answer, and I overlooked that word. It's totally fine to use that. However, I think it's easier to grasp now. Thanks for that!
